# Checking for a non-existent command

Tags: python, discord.py

Why, when I have existing commands in the array, do I check with the function on_message and nothing happens in the loop.

```
available_commands = ['/help', '/profile', '/register', '/shop', '/daily']

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('/'):
        msg = message.content
        for x in range(len(available_commands)):
            if msg != available_commands[x]:
                await message.channel.send('Unknown command! Please type /help!')
                return
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. you are checking to see if your command is EVERY SINGLE OPTION in `available_commands`, what you should instead do is check if the command is in `available_commands` (the command being the first "word" of `message.content`)
try this:

```py
available_commands = ['/help', '/profile', '/register', '/shop', '/daily']

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.content.startswith('/'):
        return
    if message.content.split()[0] not in available_commands:
        await message.channel.send('Unknown command! Please type /help!')
                return
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

If you are unfamiliar with the `in` keyword, I suggest you try reading [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-in-keyword/)

Comment: keep in mind that messages can also take arguments, so you should split `message.content` and get the first work. `if message.content.split()[0] not in ...`

Comment: It only got worse now, even if I write any text and the command will be written 5 or 4 times unknown command.

Comment: I'm novice in Python. But I know the language well Pawn.

Comment: @PressF that probably means that the bot is getting other messages, we should then skip messeges that dont start with `/`. I have updated the code to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

So ... first of all after seeing your code I can literally say that you have seen youtube tutorials ...
don't watch them first of all because they are bad and dont provide a good way to do things also some are even outdated I would recommend you to first read docs of discord.py and then join https://discord.gg/dpy/ and you can find pretty much good amount of help

as for why this code is bad

first of all if you don't know after april 30 , 2022 message content intent will be privileged and if your bot reached above 100 servers either you will need intent or you wil have to go with slash commands. (you will learn about them as you code further .... just join some coding communities like the one I mentioned above you will get good amount of info there)

next you really dont have need to check for commands if they exist or not.. what I mean is instead of using `on_message` event what you can really do is using another decorator `@bot.command()`
here is example how to do things with this

```py
@bot.command()
async def shop(message):
    #any function here that you want
    await message.send('your msg') #this will send msg ofc
```

now if suppose you havent defined a function(command) so it will raise an error `CommandNotFound` which can be detected by another bot event `on_command_error`
now how to implement this?

in the same decorator under `@bot.event` in your code you will have to do this

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    #if you still want to do something with this

async def on_command_error(message,error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        await message.send("This command don't exist")
        #or you can simply just pass this one
```

and it's not your fault for following yt tutorials lol because I also followed them at a time.... but yeah they are bad :) welcome to discord.py